can someone explain the strange recompositions that happen using datastore, outside or via lambda of main composable
I have this code where first and third surfaces(and all its content) recompose when clicking on the first surface. However, only the second and third surfaces(and all its content) recompose when clicking on the second surface.
Clicking the third composable only recomposes the switch, which is what I expect for the other two as well. This should be the standard behavior. Can someone explain why it's not working that way?
I'm using latest Compose Multiplatform with androidx DataStore, but I'm experiencing the same issue with Android Compose as well.
RecomposeCounter extends RecomposeHighlighter to include a counter display. RecomposeHighlighter
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Switch
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.collectAsState
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.window.singleWindowApplication
import androidx.datastore.core.DataStore
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.PreferenceDataStoreFactory
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.Preferences
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.booleanPreferencesKey
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.edit
import de.recomposeCounter
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.SupervisorJob
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.map
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.io.File

fun main() {
    singleWindowApplication {
        testRecompositionOfDataStorePreferences()
    }
}

private val CoroutineScopeInstance = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob())
private val DataStoreInstance: DataStore<Preferences> =
    PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create(scope = CoroutineScopeInstance) {
        File(System.getProperty("user.dir", null), "Preferences.preferences_pb")
    }

@Composable
fun testRecompositionOfDataStorePreferences() {
    val valueA by DataStoreInstance.data.map { it[booleanPreferencesKey("valueA")] ?: false }.collectAsState(false)
    val valueB by DataStoreInstance.data.map { it[booleanPreferencesKey("valueB")] ?: false }.collectAsState(false)
    val valueC by DataStoreInstance.data.map { it[booleanPreferencesKey("valueC")] ?: false }.collectAsState(false)

    Column {
        extractedWithOnClick(valueA) {
            CoroutineScopeInstance.launch {
                DataStoreInstance.edit {
                    it[booleanPreferencesKey("valueA")] = !valueA
                }
            }
        }

        extractedWithoutOnClick(valueB)

        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    CoroutineScopeInstance.launch {
                        DataStoreInstance.edit {
                            it[booleanPreferencesKey("valueC")] = !valueC
                        }
                    }
                }
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(100.dp)
                .recomposeCounter()
        ) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
                Switch(
                    modifier = Modifier.recomposeCounter(),
                    checked = valueC,
                    onCheckedChange = {
                        CoroutineScopeInstance.launch {
                            DataStoreInstance.edit {
                                it[booleanPreferencesKey("valueC")] = !valueC
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun extractedWithoutOnClick(valueB: Boolean) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable {
                CoroutineScopeInstance.launch {
                    DataStoreInstance.edit {
                        it[booleanPreferencesKey("valueB")] = !valueB
                    }
                }
            }
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(100.dp)
            .recomposeCounter()
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
            Switch(
                modifier = Modifier.recomposeCounter(),
                checked = valueB,
                onCheckedChange = {
                    CoroutineScopeInstance.launch {
                        DataStoreInstance.edit {
                            it[booleanPreferencesKey("valueB")] = !valueB
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun extractedWithOnClick(
    value: Boolean,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable(onClick = onClick)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(100.dp)
            .recomposeCounter()
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
        ) {
            Switch(
                modifier = Modifier.recomposeCounter(),
                checked = value,
                onCheckedChange = { onClick() }
            )
        }
    }
}



Edit1: One approach I've found to avoid unnecessary recompositions in other parts of the UI is to extract UI that uses preference logic into custom composables
like this:
@Composable
fun extractedMethodA() {
    val valueA by DataStoreInstance.data.map { it[booleanPreferencesKey("valueA")] ?: false }.distinctUntilChanged().collectAsState(false)
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable(onClick = {
                CoroutineScopeInstance.launch {
                    DataStoreInstance.edit {
                        it[booleanPreferencesKey("valueA")] = !valueA
                    }
                }
            })
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(100.dp)
            .recomposeCounter()
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
        ) {
            Switch(
                modifier = Modifier.recomposeCounter(),
                checked = valueA,
                onCheckedChange = {
                    CoroutineScopeInstance.launch {
                        DataStoreInstance.edit {
                            it[booleanPreferencesKey("valueA")] = !valueA
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

and in the main method:
Column {
        extractedMethodA()
        extractedMethodB()
}

result:


I don’t know if this explains everything, but I’m just browsing on my phone. You are creating your flows (using .map) inside your Composable, so even though you are collecting them as state, they may not work correctly because they become new flow instances every time it recomposes.

@Tenfour04 How would you collect it otherwise? Why doesn't it recompose if I click the third surface?

The Flows should be declared in val properties outside the Composable, somewhere they will outlive it. On Android, this would usually be in a ViewModel.

I think you need distinctUntilChanged before collecting e.g. val valueA by DataStoreInstance.data.map { it[booleanPreferencesKey("valueA")] ?: false }.distinctUntilChanged().collectAsState(false)

Unfortunately, distinctUntilChanged doesn't do anything for StateFlows. The only solution I've found to prevent unnecessary recompositions is to wrap every use of a preference value in a separate method whenever it's needed for the UI. I edit to show the case.
